# Anyone know why my Chrome browser's background-color acts up like this?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using rgba colors, but after switching to HEX the problem still persists. I never had this issue a few weeks ago, and just noticed it. All opacities on rgba colors are set to 1 (100%), so they should appear. I assume it's a new chrome bug?

The left screenshot is Safari where it works and the right is Chrome.
[safari vs chrome link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnV2n.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same to me. I found a fix! Aparently there is a bug with webkit with the backface of a div element. This code will help

```
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

You can found more info in w3schools.com -> [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp)

Comment: You have to add this line on the container element.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome appears to have some rendering bugs. Especially after GPU Driver Updates or Chrome Updates. A friend of mine had them for months.
You could try tuo update your drivers but theres no guarantee it helps.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try that and see if that changes things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same happens to me. I tried to download Chrome beta. The weird rectangles do not appear there but the background color still does not act as it is supposed to. You can take a look at my [page](http://marekfort.com) - the blue background color magically changes itself as soon as the whole landing page disappears.

Comment: That's very interesting why that happens. I like the color changing on your website!

Comment: Thanks! Too bad it is not working as of right now :/ Post an update if you find any way to resolve this issue.